# Post build action in Jenkins throws NullPointerException

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I can't find what is the problem. Can anyone help to deal with the `NullPointerException` after post build action in Jenkins when I need to send report with the Notify.Events plugin?

```
    post {
    always {
step([$class: 'Publisher', reportFilenamePattern: '**/testng-results.xml'])
}
unstable {
step([$class: 'NotifyEventsBuilder', token: '6CGdLVTZUPWaQsz7qIGN52KRHSDuYdup', message: 'UNSTABLE TEST'])
}
failure {
step([$class: 'NotifyEventsBuilder', token: '6CGdLVTZUPWaQsz7qIGN52KRHSDuYdup', message: 'FAIL TEST'])
}
success {
step([$class: 'NotifyEventsBuilder', token: '6CGdLVTZUPWaQsz7qIGN52KRHSDuYdup', message: 'SUCCESSFUL TEST'])
 }
 unsuccessful {
step([$class: 'NotifyEventsBuilder', token: '6CGdLVTZUPWaQsz7qIGN52KRHSDuYdup', message: 'unsuccessful TEST'])
 }
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
    [Pipeline] step
Error when executing success post condition:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at events.notify.NotifyEventsService.send(NotifyEventsService.java:159)
    at events.notify.NotifyEventsBuilder.perform(NotifyEventsBuilder.java:138)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

[Pipeline] step
Error when executing unsuccessful post condition:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at events.notify.NotifyEventsService.send(NotifyEventsService.java:159)
    at events.notify.NotifyEventsBuilder.perform(NotifyEventsBuilder.java:138)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

[Pipeline] step
Error when executing failure post condition:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at events.notify.NotifyEventsService.send(NotifyEventsService.java:159)
    at events.notify.NotifyEventsBuilder.perform(NotifyEventsBuilder.java:138)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at events.notify.NotifyEventsService.send(NotifyEventsService.java:159)
    at events.notify.NotifyEventsBuilder.perform(NotifyEventsBuilder.java:138)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using? Aren't you supposed to use something like this in declarative Pipeline? `notifyEvents message: 'Hello <b>world</b>', token: '01234567890123456789012345678901'`

Comment: It is 1.6.2 version